# In $D_{2n}$ if $(r^i \Delta^j) (r^k \Delta^l)=r^m \Delta^n$ then compute $m,n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

In Dihedral group $D_{2n'}=\langle r,\Delta\mid r^{n^{'}}=\Delta^2=1,\Delta r \Delta^{-1}=r^{-1}\rangle $. Now compute $m,n$ in terms of $i,j,k,l$ from
$(r^i \Delta^j) (r^k \Delta^l)=r^m \Delta^n$

now $(r^i \Delta^j) (r^k \Delta^l)=(r^i \Delta \Delta^{j-1})( r^k \Delta^l)=(r^i \Delta^{-1} )(\Delta^{j-1} r^k \Delta^l)=(\Delta^{-1}(\Delta r^i \Delta^{-1} ))(\Delta^{j-1} r^k \Delta^l)=(\Delta^{-1}(\Delta r \Delta^{-1} \Delta r \Delta^{-1}...\Delta r \Delta^{-1} ))(\Delta^{j-1} r^k \Delta^l)=\Delta^{-1} r^{-i}(\Delta^{j-1} r^k \Delta^l)$.

now I can't understand what to do, how to get the form $r^m \Delta^n$.I think I am making this more complicated. any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Is this identity true for all $i,j,k,l?$

Comment: @PCeltide yeah I think so

Comment: I assume you mean the $n$ in $D_{2n}$ and the $n$ in $r^m\Delta^n$ to be different in general?

Comment: @DavidSheard yeah yeah its different. i should have notice that. well now i have edited the $n$ of $D_{2n}$ to $n'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $s_1=\Delta$ and $s_2=\Delta r$. You can check that $\{s_1,s_2\}$ generate $D_{2n}$ with presentation $$\langle s_1,s_2\mid s_1^2=s_2^2=(s_1s_2)^n=1\rangle.$$ This is the Coxeter presentation of $D_{2n}$. Note that $r=s_1s_2$. Given $i,j,k,l$ we can compute \begin{equation}r^i\Delta^j r^k\Delta^l=(s_1s_2)^is_1^j(s_1s_2)^ks_1^l.\tag{1}\end{equation}

If $j$ is even, $s_1^j=1$, so $(1)$ becomes $$(s_1s_2)^i(s_1s_2)^ks_1^l=(s_1s_2)^{i+k}s_1^l=r^{i+k}\Delta^l.$$

If $j$ is odd, $s_1^j=s_1$, so $(1)$ becomes $$(s_1s_2)^is_1s_1(s_2s_1)^{k}s_1^{l-1}=(s_1s_2)^{i-k}s_1^{l-1}=r^{i-k}\Delta^{l-1},$$ using the fact that $(s_1s_2)^ks_1=s_1s_2s_1\cdots s_1=s_1(s_2s_1)^k$.

Thus $r^i\Delta^j r^k\Delta^l=r^a\Delta^b$ where $$a=\begin{cases}
i+k\;(\textrm{mod}\;n) &\textrm{if}\;j\;\textrm{is even}\\
i-k\;(\textrm{mod}\;n) &\textrm{if}\;j\;\textrm{is odd}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$b=\begin{cases}
l\;(\textrm{mod}\;2) &\textrm{if}\;j\;\textrm{is even}\\
l-1\;(\textrm{mod}\;2) &\textrm{if}\;j\;\textrm{is odd}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. this is a very innovative way to solve this. and I think this can't be solved  by the manupulation of $\Delta r \Delta^{-1}=r^{-1}$. what do you think?

Comment: This method is much easier than working with $r$ and $\Delta$ because those generators are very different (one a rotation one a reflection), whereas the generators $s_1$ and $s_2$ are on an even footing (both reflections)  making some manipulations easier. It would certainly be possible to solve using $\Delta r\Delta^{-1}=r^{-1}$, but spotting where to split into cases is less easy. Also it takes more steps, for example the single step $(s_1s_2)^ks_1=s_1(s_2s_1)^k$ requires either induction on $k$ or comfort with conjugation to prove the equivalent formula $r^k\Delta=\Delta r^k$.

Comment: I think the only mazor trick you have done is considering  whether $j$ is even or odd, beacause by similar approach and using the induction $r^i \Delta = \Delta r^{-i}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ we can solve this for generator $r,\Delta$ also. as if $j$ is even then $\Delta^j=1$ so $r^i r^k \Delta^l=r^{i+k}  \Delta^l$. and if $j$ is odd then  $\Delta^j=\Delta$ so  $r^i \Delta r^k \Delta^l=(r^i \Delta) r^k \Delta^l= \Delta r^{-i} r^k \Delta^l=(\Delta r^{-i+k} ) \Delta^l=r^{i-k} \Delta^{l+1}$ and the similar result follows. and i think $r^k \Delta \neq \Delta r^k$ as $r \Delta \neq \Delta r$

Comment: And I also think that without considering even or odd, if we want solve it by the only manipulation of $\Delta r \Delta^{-1}=r^{-1}$, it will be quite difficult.